# CUPS jobs no longer showing on web UI

Tags: printing, cups

I send multiple jobs daily to a remote CUPS server. These jobs print successfully and were showing on the webui as in progress and then completed/all jobs.

Recently, it stopped showing any new jobs status or completion - jobs print, but they are not showing. They do in exist in /var/spool/cups - just not the webui.

Test pages printed via the webui do show up in jobs on the webui.
I haven't been able to find any configuration item that handles this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 instances of the cups daemon running.  Killed one and all jobs started showing back up...